# Different options for creating a real time notification system

Tags: node.js, rest, websocket, notifications

I want to create a real time notification system but am unsure on what the best architecture would be.

This is the journey my app will take.

1. React app calls a POST API in Node which updates the notification table.

Now this is where I'm unsure.

Either another user who is looking for this notification, continuously polls a notification API every 10 seconds or so to get notifications or we use some sort of websocket.

I feel like the polling method would be a lot more intensive and be harder to scale.

In the websocket I basically plan to poll the database every 10 seconds, unless there is a way for a trigger in the database to call the websocket etc..

Are there any thoughts on this, or any option I've missed out?

My tech stack is Node, React MYSQL, if that matters at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do when it comes to the notifications. For a real-time app I would use socket.io. Are the mentioned notifications meant to alert other users that a new user has joined? If so, that's pretty easy to do with socket.io as well. You can also retrieve information from a db everytime a new user connects to the socket like this (MongoDB with Mongoose):

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/DBNAME', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

let exampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ....
  ....
})
let exampleModel = new mongoose.model("exampleModel", exampleSchema )

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/ExampleDB', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
```

The code below will search your entire db every time a new socket connection is established. It will then emit the notification data to all connected sockets.

```
let io = new sio(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    exampleModel.find({}, (err, data)=> {
       const notification = JSON.stringify(data.notification)
       io.emit('notificationFromDB', notification)
      })
    })
```

Maybe you could elaborate more on what you are trying to do and I can try to help you with your problem.

Update 10/21/2020 9:40PM PST:

The code below will receive the bookComment from the client and broadcast it afterwards to all connected clients:

```
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      socket.on('bookComment', (comment) => {
        //save comment to database here or perform other operations
        io.emit('broadcastComment', comment)
  })
})
```

Please let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: I'm trying to make a mobile app which allows a group of people to write notes under different sentences for a given book.

The part I'm stuck at is coming up with the architecture of when a one person writes a note under one sentence in the book, it should send a notification to everyone else. Thanks!